# Php Curl request and SSL Error

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have to make a request to a web-service using php curl.
I have to use this code to generate the request:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

I often get an error: `SSL Error` when I try to make the request curl.

On average I have to make about 2 requests (with this error) before getting a good request with the correct result.

Something wrong?

I'm not interested in the absolutely to SSL. The service that I have to invoke use  HTTPS.

Comment: Do you have the SSL certificates for that host? If you do, take a look at cURL option `CURLOPT_CAPATH`. If you don't, then remove `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or set it to `0` and try again.

Comment: This not solve the problem